# Modx gallery stopped working on all sites

Tags: php, gallery, imagick, modx-revolution

The modx gallery extra suddenly stopped working on all my sites [on the same server] I've checked permissions and paths ~ they are fine. tested imagick ~ it is fine the only thing I can guess at is something to do with the php configuration.

**UPDATE**

OK, the gallery CAN upload zip files but still not individual or multi files, it seems to need the ZIP upload to create the gallery directory first ~THEN~ it can upload individual files.

here is the error from one of the sites:

```
[root@ httpd]# cat  /vhome/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/core/cache/logs/error.log
[2014-07-25 13:19:13] (ERROR @ /assets/components/gallery/connector.php) [Gallery] Could not create directory (possibly already exists?): assets/gallery/14/
[2014-07-25 13:19:14] (ERROR @ /assets/components/gallery/connector.php) [phpThumbOf] Could not generate thumbnail: /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg - Debug: Array
(
    [0] => phpThumb() v1.7.11-201108081537 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 216
    [1] => setCacheDirectory() starting with config_cache_directory = "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/core/cache/phpthumb/" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 958
    [2] => setting config_cache_directory to realpath(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/core/cache/phpthumb) = "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/core/cache/phpthumb" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 986
    [3] => ResolveFilenameToAbsolute() prepending $this->config_document_root (/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/) to $filename (/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg) resulting in ($AbsoluteFilename = "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs//assets/gallery/14/131.jpg") in file "modphpthumb.class.php" on line 262
    [4] => setSourceFilename(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs//assets/gallery/14/131.jpg) set $this->sourceFilename to "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs//assets/gallery/14/131.jpg" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 262
    [5] => setCacheDirectory() starting with config_cache_directory = "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/components/gallery/cache/" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 958
    [6] => setting config_cache_directory to realpath(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/components/gallery/cache) = "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/components/gallery/cache" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 986
    [7] => setSourceFilename(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg) set $this->sourceFilename to "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 262
    [8] => CleanUpCacheDirectory() set to purge (30.0 days; 100.00 MB; 10,000 files) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 673
    [9] => CleanUpCacheDirectory() skipped because "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/components/gallery/cache/phpThumbCacheStats.txt" is recently modified in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 683
    [10] =>                   file_exists() = 0 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1165
    [11] => file_exists_ignoreopenbasedir() = 0 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1166
    [12] =>                       is_file() = 0 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1167
    [13] =>                 is_executable() = 0 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1168
    [14] => using ImageMagick path from `which convert` (/usr/bin/convert) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1188
    [15] => ImageMagick version checked with "convert --version" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1215
    [16] => ImageMagick convert --version says "Version: ImageMagick 6.2.8 05/07/12 Q16 file:" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1223
    [17] => Addding ImageMagick formats to $AvailableImageOutputFormats (text;ico;bmp;wbmp;gif;png;jpeg) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 917
    [18] => $AvailableImageOutputFormats = array(text;ico;bmp;wbmp;gif;png;jpeg) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 923
    [19] => $this->thumbnailFormat set to $this->config_output_format "jpeg" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 934
    [20] => $this->thumbnailFormat set to $this->f "jpeg" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 941
    [21] => $this->thumbnailQuality set to "75" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 951
    [22] => ResolveFilenameToAbsolute() NOT prepending $this->config_document_root (/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/) to $filename (/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg) resulting in ($AbsoluteFilename = "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg") in file "modphpthumb.class.php" on line 259
    [23] => $this->sourceFilename set to "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 852
    [24] => phpThumb() v1.7.11-201108081537
http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net

Error messages disabled in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3845
    [25] => setCacheDirectory() starting with config_cache_directory = "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/components/gallery/cache" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 958
    [26] => setting config_cache_directory to realpath(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/components/gallery/cache) = "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/components/gallery/cache" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 986
    [27] => SetCacheFilename() _src set from md5($this->sourceFilename) "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg" = "a12a2d06507250d96ef5e54541cbf2de" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3238
    [28] => SetCacheFilename() _par set from md5(_farC_zc1_h100_w100_dpi150_q75) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3271
    [29] => starting ExtractEXIFgetImageSize() in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3033
    [30] => GetImageSize(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg) says image is x in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3043
    [31] => GetImageSize("/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg") failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3076
    [32] => $this->useRawIMoutput=true after checking $UnAllowedParameters in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1315
    [33] => phpThumb_tempnam() returning "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/components/gallery/pThumbzv1vUI" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 4070
    [34] => ImageMagickSwitchAvailable(thumbnail) = 1 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1255
    [35] => ImageMagickSwitchAvailable(density) = 1 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1255
    [36] => GetImageSize(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg) FAILED with error "" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1409
    [37] => GetImageSize(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg) failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1556
    [38] => Remaining $this->fltr after ImageMagick: (array(0) { } ) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1939
    [39] => ImageMagickSwitchAvailable(quality;interlace) = 1 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1252
    [40] => ImageMagick called as (convert -density '150' -thumbnail '100x100' -quality '75' -interlace line  '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg[0]' jpeg:'/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/components/gallery/pThumbzv1vUI' 2>&1) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1958
    [41] => ImageMagick failed with message (convert: unable to open image `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg': No such file or directory.
convert: missing an image filename `jpeg:/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/components/gallery/pThumbzv1vUI'.) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1963
    [42] => deleting "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/components/gallery/pThumbzv1vUI" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1991
    [43] => ImageMagickThumbnailToGD() failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3083
    [44] => SetOrientationDependantWidthHeight() starting with ""x"" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3012
    [45] => SetOrientationDependantWidthHeight() setting w="100", h="100" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3028
    [46] => EXIF thumbnail extraction: (size=0; type=""; 0x0) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3140
    [47] => starting SourceImageToGD() in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3398
    [48] => starting ImageCreateFromFilename(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3313
    [49] => empty $filename or GetImageSize(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg) failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3362
    [50] => Populating $rawimagedata in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3370
    [51] => cannot fopen(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3381
    [52] => Not using EXIF thumbnail data because $this->exif_thumbnail_data is empty in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3469
    [53] => $this->gdimg_source is still empty in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3521
    [54] => ImageMagickThumbnailToGD() failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3523
    [55] => phpThumb() v1.7.11-201108081537
http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net

Error messages disabled in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3845
    [56] => SourceImageToGD() failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 342
)
```

Comment: `cannot fopen (/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/assets/gallery/14/131.jpg) ` - is this file really exist?

Comment: no it does not, it cannot even create the directory.

Comment: So, what did you change.

Comment: nothing was changed or updated [apache config, or php. the modx sites, some are older some newer but all the gallery ones are 2.2.14]

Comment: Nothing was changed....it just stopped working?

Comment: I noticed it stopped working when a user complained about it. I'm not 100% sure it ever actually worked.

Comment: @SeanKimball I am experiencing this exact error (nearly line for line). Gallery was working just fine on my site, too, and then just randomly stopped working.

Comment: Is it possible the permissions are wrong? I upgraded to modx 2.3.3 and got the same error, and was able to fix it by doing a chown -R on the httpdocs folder.